# How to initialize a variable with n number of bits in VHDL?

Tags: variables, generics, binary, vhdl, multiplication

so basically I'm trying to do a multiplier in VHDL with 2 inputs of N bits with an output of 2*N bits. I'm just a beginner in this language so I've tried to make a simple code without using some advanced tools/terms. So here's what I've got:

[My code in VHDL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8WQb.png)

Their is an error right between the initialization of the variables and the loop. I think that everything after the loop is correctly written so the problem can only be the variables. I want to have variables that could, like the entries, have a variable number of bits depending on N (initialize in Generic). I also want to initialize some of their bits to 0.

Bvariable would only be half of the bits (The MSB) and the other half would take the bits of Y.

Pvariable would have all of his bits with the value 0.

Some addition info for variables for those who want more clarification:

1.The Bvariable is B with more bits and shifted to the left in the loop.

2.The Pvariable is P but we're changing constantly his value before attribute it to P.

Here's my problem. Hope that you could help me find answers. Also, feel free to propose me another way to build a multiplier if it is relatively simple (like with signals instead of variables).

Thank you for your time.

[My code in VHDL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8WQb.png)

Comment: Should you think it suitable to provide only a picture of your code how about [a picture of the problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/992Ek.jpg). [Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). See: How to create a [mcve]. You could take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. It makes it difficult for people to copy and paste your code to try and run it or post answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the resize function for an existing unsigned:

```
variable Bvariable : unsigned(2*N-1 downto 0) := resize(Y, Bvariable'length);
```

or the to_unsigned function for an integer literal

```
variable Pvariable : unsigned(2*N-1 downto 0) := to_unsigned(0, Pvariable'length);
```